# How to prove Minimum Mean Squared Error based cost function is a convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

To Prove that $J(\omega)$ is Convex,

$J(\omega) = \min_{\omega}|D(n) - \mathbf{\omega^{T}(n)y(n)}|^{2}$

Where,
$\omega \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the Filter Weight Vector.

$y(n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is Received Observation.

$D(n) \in \mathbb{R}$ is a Desired Signal.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please review guidelines on how to ask a good question. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Firstly, what have you tried to solve this question?
Second, it looks like there is a notational error in the definition of J: As-written, $J(\omega)$ is always a fixed number. If this is correct, then we're done since every constant function is convex.